# React getDerivedStateFromProps update array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with updating component state by getDerivedStateFromProps.
In my component state I have few arrays, but returning value in getDerivedStateFromProps
doesn't seem to update them at all :<

My code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps (nextProps, prevState) {
let result = null

// always the same
// nextProps.mainObject have all data I need
// but all component state arrays are empty

if (nextProps.mainObject && nextProps.mainObject.parameters && nextProps.mainObject.parameters.length &&
  !_.isEqual(nextProps.mainObject.parameters, prevState.parameters)) {
  result = {
    parameters: nextProps.mainObject.parameters
  }

  let parameterOneList = nextProps.mainObject.parameters.filter(item => item.type === 'one')
  let parameterTwoList = nextProps.mainObject.parameters.filter(item => item.type === 'two')
  let parameterThreeList = nextProps.mainObject.parameters.filter(item => item.type === 'three')

  if (!_.isEqual(parameterOneList, prevState.parameterOneList)) {
    result.parameterOneList = parameterOneList
  }
  if (!_.isEqual(parameterTwoList, prevState.parameterTwoList)) {
    result.parameterTwoList = parameterTwoList
  }
  if (!_.isEqual(parameterThreeList, prevState.parameterThreeList)) {
    result.parameterThreeList = parameterThreeList
  }
}

if (nextProps.mainObject && nextProps.mainObject.otherParameters && nextProps.mainObject.otherParameters.length &&
  !_.isEqual(nextProps.mainObject.otherParameters, prevState.otherParameters)) {
  // check if result was changed already by parameters
  if (result) {
   result.otherParameters = nextProps.mainObject.otherParameters
  } else {
    result = {
     otherParameters: nextProps.mainObject.otherParameters
    }
  }
}

// always the same
// all data in result looks great, arrays are filled with data

return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try assign all array properties from `nextProps` to constants
It should work:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) { 
        const _anyArray = nextProps.anyArray
        return {
           anyArray: _anyArray
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to read all the post: in  getDerivedStateFromProps return i have all properly settled data, but it won't update component state - what constant's have to do with it?